# NotImplementedError: Supported modes strings are 'r', 'rb', 'rt', 'w', 'wb', and 'wt' only

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

> NotImplementedError: Supported modes strings are 'r', 'rb', 'rt', 'w', 'wb', and 'wt' only.

While running **Kafka** on **GCP**, with the python codes and I am working with producer and consumer, getting ended up writing consumer in **GCS** bucket.

But here is the error I am facing while importing message offsets in **GCS**:

```
NotImplementedError: Supported modes strings are 'r', 'rb', 'rt', 'w', 'wb', and 'wt' only.
```

And here is my code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
 storage_client = storage.Client()
 bucket = storage_client.bucket("kafka-gcptest")
 blob = bucket.blob('stock_market')
 for count, i in enumerate(consumer):
     with blob.open("gs://kafka-gcptest/stock_market_{}.json".format(count), 'w') as file:
         json.dump(i.value, file)
```

Comment: 1) Removed Kafka tags. Your error is coming from GCS 2) You should use Kafka Connect to write *batches of data* to GCS, not one record at a time from Kafka. Most importantly, the `count` is not a same as the Kafka record offset, and can reset and overwrite any GCS file

Comment: The error message seems to be telling you that the argument to `open` should be a mode indicator, not a URL. Read the method's documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `bucket.blob` sets the name of the blob; the `open` method uses that name and only needs a mode to open it for writing.

```
from google.cloud import storage


storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket("kafka-gcptest")

for count, i in enumerate(consumer):
    blob = bucket.blob(f'stock_market_{count}.json')
    with blob.open('w') as file:
        json.dump(i.value, file)
```